# crank motion with svg

Tags: javascript, math, svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="1100"
    height="600">

  <title>  Slider-Crank </title>

  <defs>
    <rect
                id="Slidebar"
      stroke-width="1"
            stroke="black"
              fill="silver"
      fill-opacity="1"
                 x="0"
                 y="-12"
             width="300"
            height="24"
    />
    <g id="Crosshead" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="1">
      <rect
           fill="gold"
              x="-50"
              y="-25"
          width="100"
         height="50"
      />
      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="white"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Crank" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="1">
      <path fill="silver"
             d="M -99.959 40.000
                A  40  40 0 0 1 -99.959, -40.000
                A 450 450 0 0 0  -9.950, -49.000
                A  50  50 0 1 1  -9.950,  49.000
                A 450 450 0 0 0 -99.959,  40.000
                z"/>
      <circle cx="-100" cy="0" r="25" fill="white"/>
      <circle cx="0"    cy="0" r="30" fill="lightgrey"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ConRod" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.7">
      <path fill="silver"
             d="M  12.387  21.715
                A 30 30 0 0 1  27.551  17.776
                L 453.475  22.035
                A 30 30 0 0 1 473.243  29.733
                A 40 40 0 0 1 473.243 -29.733
                A 30 30 0 0 1 453.475 -22.035
                L  27.551 -17.776
                A 30 30 0 0 1 12.387  -21.715
                A 25 25 0 0 1 12.387   21.715
                z"/>
      <circle cx="0"   cy="0" r="25" fill="silver"/>
      <circle cx="0"   cy="0" r="15" fill="white"/>
      <circle cx="500" cy="0" r="40" fill="silver"/>
      <circle cx="500" cy="0" r="25" fill="white"/>
    </g>

  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#Slidebar"  x="150" y="263"/>
  <use xlink:href="#Slidebar"  x="150" y="337"/>
  <use xlink:href="#Crosshead" x="200" y="300">
    <animate
      attributeName="x"
            dur="3s"
            values="  200.000;
                      207.202;
                      227.545;
                      257.557;
                      292.430;
                      327.159;
                      357.557;
                      380.753;
                      395.140;
                      400.000;
                      395.140;
                      380.753;
                      357.557;
                      327.159;
                      292.430;
                      257.557;
                      227.545;
                      207.202;
                      200.000"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>

  <use xlink:href="#Crank" x="800" y="300">
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0,800,300"
         by="360" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <use xlink:href="#ConRod" x="200" y="300">
    <animate
      attributeName="x"
            dur="3s"
            values="  200.000;
                      207.202;
                      227.545;
                      257.557;
                      292.430;
                      327.159;
                      357.557;
                      380.753;
                      395.140;
                      400.000;
                      395.140;
                      380.753;
                      357.557;
                      327.159;
                      292.430;
                      257.557;
                      227.545;
                      207.202;
                      200.000"

        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0,200,300"
         repeatCount="indefinite" dur="3s"
         values="  0.000, 200.000, 300;
                  -3.922, 207.202, 300;
                  -7.386, 227.545, 300;
                  -9.974, 257.557, 300;
                 -11.359, 292.430, 300;
                 -11.359, 327.159, 300;
                  -9.974, 357.557, 300;
                  -7.386, 380.753, 300;
                  -3.922, 395.140, 300;
                   0.000, 400.000, 300;
                   3.922, 395.140, 300;
                   7.386, 380.753, 300;
                   9.974, 357.557, 300;
                  11.359, 327.159, 300;
                  11.359, 292.430, 300;
                   9.974, 257.557, 300;
                   7.386, 227.545, 300;
                   3.922, 207.202, 300;
                   0.000, 200.000, 300"/>
  </use>

</svg>
```

Hi I'm trying to reproduce this crank motion animation with svg and javascript.
The Crosshead need a translate animation and the Crank a rotation animation but how could I get the ConRod animation ?
In the svg there is values given to animate and animateTransform but is there an equation which allow us to reproduce this ?
Does anyone have an idea

Comment: The animation is in `<animate>` and `<animateTransform>`

Comment: I think it is easier to go from crank rotation. You rotate crank by changing the angle, then you get the position of joint with conrod. Conrod has same length each time, so we have hypotenuse and cathetus (y position of first joint). Then we get the position of second joint (conrod with crosshead) - the position of crosshead. Now it is only needed to connect joints with two lines to get conrod drawn. Or we get origin of rotation for conrod and the angle of its rotation (using positions of joints).

Answer (score 1):

```js
{
    const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    const crank = svg.querySelector('#crank');
    const crosshead = svg.querySelector('#crosshead');
    const conrod = svg.querySelector('#conrod');
    const bar_rect = svg.querySelector('#slidebar');
    
    const bar1 = svg.querySelector('#bar1');
    const bar2 = svg.querySelector('#bar2');
    
    // You can change those a bit
    const center = [800,150];
    const crank_len = 100;
    const conrod_len = 500;
    const crosshead_len = 100;
    const rotation_speed = 1;
        
    bar_rect.setAttribute('width', crank_len*2 + crosshead_len);
    bar1.setAttribute('y', center[1] - 37.5);
    bar1.setAttribute('x', center[0] - crank_len - conrod_len - crosshead_len/2);
    bar2.setAttribute('y', center[1] + 37.5);
    bar2.setAttribute('x', center[0] - crank_len - conrod_len - crosshead_len/2);
    
    crosshead.querySelector('rect').setAttribute('x', -crosshead_len/2);
    crosshead.querySelector('rect').setAttribute('width', crosshead_len);
    
    let angle = 0;
    
    draw();

    function draw(){
    
        crank.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${center[0]},${center[1]}) rotate(${angle+180}, 0, 0) scale(${crank_len/100})`);
        
        let crank_x = center[0] + Math.cos(angle*(Math.PI/180))*crank_len;
        let crank_y = center[1] + Math.sin(angle*(Math.PI/180))*crank_len;
        
        let crosshead_x = crank_x - Math.sqrt(conrod_len**2 - (crank_y-center[1])**2);
        let crosshead_y = center[1];
        
        crosshead.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${crosshead_x},${crosshead_y})`);
        
        let conrod_angle = Math.acos((crank_x-crosshead_x)/conrod_len)*(180/Math.PI);
        
        conrod_angle = (crank_y > center[1])? conrod_angle : -conrod_angle;
        
        conrod.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${crosshead_x},${crosshead_y}) rotate(${conrod_angle},0,0) scale(${conrod_len/500})`);

                
        angle = angle%(360) + rotation_speed;
        
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);        
    }

}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1100 600">
    <defs>
        <rect
            id="slidebar"
            stroke-width="1"
            stroke="black"
            fill="silver"
            fill-opacity="1"
            x="0"
            y="-12"
            width="300"
            height="24"
        />

    </defs>

    <use id="bar1" xlink:href="#slidebar"/>
    <use id="bar2" xlink:href="#slidebar"/>

    <g id="crosshead" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="1">
        <rect
            fill="gold"
            x="-50"
            y="-25"
            width="100"
            height="50"
        />
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="white"/>
    </g>

    <g id="crank" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="1">
        <path fill="silver"
            d="M -99.959 40.000
                A  40  40 0 0 1 -99.959, -40.000
                A 450 450 0 0 0  -9.950, -49.000
                A  50  50 0 1 1  -9.950,  49.000
                A 450 450 0 0 0 -99.959,  40.000
                z"/>
        <circle cx="-100" cy="0" r="25" fill="white"/>
        <circle cx="0"    cy="0" r="30" fill="lightgrey"/>
    </g>
    <g id="conrod" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0.7">
        <path fill="silver"
                d="M  12.387  21.715
                    A 30 30 0 0 1  27.551  17.776
                    L 453.475  22.035
                    A 30 30 0 0 1 473.243  29.733
                    A 40 40 0 0 1 473.243 -29.733
                    A 30 30 0 0 1 453.475 -22.035
                    L  27.551 -17.776
                    A 30 30 0 0 1 12.387  -21.715
                    A 25 25 0 0 1 12.387   21.715
                    z"/>
        <circle cx="0"   cy="0" r="25" fill="silver"/>
        <circle cx="0"   cy="0" r="15" fill="white"/>
        <circle cx="500" cy="0" r="40" fill="silver"/>
        <circle cx="500" cy="0" r="25" fill="white"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! everything works when the size of the crank mechanism is changed. 
 I changed in the range `const crank_len = 50 -250`  
 `const conrod_len 250 -700`
  `crosshead_len 50 -200` everything works!